# How to divide two dataframes of different shape with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes with the same index but different shape and I'm unable to divide the columns from dataframe `df1` with the column in dataframe `df2`.

Expected result is `df1 / df2`.

```
df1.head()
                           volume  volume        volume         volume  \
timestamp                                                                
2016-07-24 00:00:00+00:00     NaN     NaN           NaN            NaN   
2016-07-25 00:00:00+00:00     NaN     NaN           NaN            NaN   
2016-07-26 00:00:00+00:00     NaN     NaN           NaN  102720.829507   
2016-07-27 00:00:00+00:00     NaN     NaN  3.729644e+05  398346.509801   
2016-07-28 00:00:00+00:00     NaN     NaN  1.326648e+06  244165.794698   

                           volume        volume  volume        volume  
timestamp                                                              
2016-07-24 00:00:00+00:00     NaN           NaN     NaN  1.734943e+07  
2016-07-25 00:00:00+00:00     NaN           NaN     NaN  1.365341e+07  
2016-07-26 00:00:00+00:00     NaN           NaN     NaN  5.199938e+07  
2016-07-27 00:00:00+00:00     NaN  2.471076e+06     NaN  2.558753e+07  
2016-07-28 00:00:00+00:00     NaN  1.642990e+06     NaN  3.118785e+06

df2.head()

timestamp
2016-07-24 00:00:00+00:00    1.734943e+07
2016-07-25 00:00:00+00:00    1.365341e+07
2016-07-26 00:00:00+00:00    5.210210e+07
2016-07-27 00:00:00+00:00    2.882991e+07
2016-07-28 00:00:00+00:00    6.332589e+06
Freq: D, dtype: float64

df1.shape
Out[2126]: (723, 8)

df2.shape
Out[2127]: (723,)

df1.divide(df2, axis= 'index')
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5784,) (723,)
```

Both dataframe have different structure but index is the same.

```
type(df1)
Out[2143]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

type(df2)
Out[2144]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

I've read that I need to reshape one of the dataframe so I've try something like this :

```
df1.divide(df2.reshape(723,1), axis= 'index')
```

But it returns an error :

```
ValueError: Unable to coerce to DataFrame, shape must be (723, 8): given (723, 1)
```

When I convert `df2` with `pd.DataFrame(df2)` then it throws an error  :

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

What am'I missing and how can I do this ?

Comment: Please, provide expected output

Comment: Hi, the expected output is `df1 / fd2`

Comment: I have found that one of my column in `df1` has `dtype: object` whereas the others have `float64`. This was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach. I have used a simple example, but let me know if that doesn't work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import display, HTML

CSS = """
.output {
    flex-direction: row;
}
"""

HTML('<style>{}</style>'.format(CSS))


data1 = {"a":[1.,7.,12.],
         "b":[4.,8.,3.],
         "c":[5.,45.,67.]}
data2 = {"a":[3.],
         "b":[2.],
         "c":[8.]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2) 
df2 = df2.T
df2 = df2.reset_index()
del df2['index']
display(df1)
display(df2)
display(df1.iloc[:,0:].truediv(df2[0], axis=0)) # this portion of code you want
```

a   b   c
0   1.0 4.0 5.0
1   7.0 8.0 45.0
2   12.0    3.0 67.0

0
0   3.0
1   2.0
2   8.0

a   b   c
0   0.333333    1.333333    1.666667
1   3.500000    4.000000    22.500000
2   1.500000    0.375000    8.375000

Comment: I can divide one column of `df1` with the column of `df2` but as soon as there is multiple columns in `df1` it fails. For example this works fine `df1.ix[:, 3].div(df2, axis="index")` but `df1.div(df2, axis="index")` doesn't return the expected result.

Comment: Yeah, you're right..df1.div(df2, axis="index") won't work, but if you're to use '.div' in this manner, then you will have to specify indexes on df1 as I have shown in my example. df1 has 3 columns, df2 has 1 column (equal number of rows), works for all examples I have tested, irrespective of columns in df1. I'll keep looking for alternative approaches.

Comment: Yes it should work, also I have found that one of the column had `dtype : object` and it was the reason of the failure.

Answer (score 1):

Indexing the respective column/s in each dataframes while using the divide (or div) function should work.

```
df1[['column_1','column_2']].divide(df2[['column_1']], axis= 'index')  

df1[['column_1','column_2']].div(df2[['column_1']], axis= 'index')
```

Comment: The name of the 8 columns in `df1` is 'volume' and there is no name for the column in `df2`.